# Resizing SVG for precise printing

Tags: d3.js, resize

I'm working on a little project to print scaled down archery targets for practice at shorter range indoors. For example, the target face shown [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1667699/Target_Scaler.html):

[image]

...is 16cm in diameter at full size for 20 yards, but needs to be printed at half that size for practice at 10 yards. There are many different styles of target faces, and I'd like to support as many as possible. I have D3 working to pull the relevant sizes from a CSV file.

I'm specifying the sizes of the elements of the SVG in centimeters whenever possible. Is it possible to use D3 to generate a PDF that can be printed at a specific size?

Here's my code that loads the CSV and generates the SVG.

```
var dataset;
var w = "16cm";
var h = "16cm";

d3.csv("./data/nfaa5spot.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(data);

        // Hand data off to global var for processing
        dataset = data;
        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
            .attr("viewBox", "-400,-400,1700,1700");

        var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(dataset)
           .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr({
                cx: function(d) { return d["cx"]; },
                cy: function(d) { return d["cy"]; },
                r: function(d) { return d["r"]; }
            })
            .style("fill", function(d) { return d["fill"]; })
            .style("stroke", function(d) { return d["stroke"]; })
            .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return d["stroke-width"]; });
    }
});
```

Here are the contents of the relevant CSV file:

```
r,cx,cy,fill,stroke,stroke-width
16cm,8cm,8cm,#164687,#164687,0
12cm,8cm,8cm,#164687,white,3
8cm,8cm,8cm,white,white,0
4cm,8cm,8cm,white,#164687,3
```

Resizing is just first part. I'm also working on drawing additional lines on the target face to compensate for arrow shaft diameter at shorter range. Fun project, and a good intro to working with D3.